# How to avoid the error 'array expected string given' in db_query

Tags: 7, users, database

I am getting this error: Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be an array,
string given. In **db_query** in below function.

```
function uc_guest_checkout_uc_checkout_complete($order, $account) {
  if (!empty($_SESSION['uc_guest_checkout'])  && !user_is_logged_in()) {
    switch ($order->data['complete_sale']) {
      case 'new_user':
        // For guest checkout, we replace the ubercart generated username and email
        // for a new user with one that is more anonymous.
        $name = uniqid('anon-', TRUE);
        $mail = $name . '.' . uc_store_email();        
        db_query('UPDATE {users} SET name = "%s", mail = "%s" WHERE uid = %d', $name, $mail, $account->uid);   
   break;
  case 'logged_in':
    // If the order is marked logged in but anonymous, this means that 
    // we must have set the uid to the default account, but still treat
    // this as a new user.
    $order->data['complete_sale'] = 'new_user';
    break;
    }
  }
  _uc_guest_checkout_end();
}
```

I tried this queries but none were creating account with valid names and emails as per db_query which is throwing error but successfully creating user accounts.where as these below queries creating names with random names.

```
db_update('users')
        ->fields(array(
            'name' => $name,
            'mail' => $mail
        ))
        ->condition('uid', $account->uid)       
        ->execute();

db_query('UPDATE {users} SET name = :name, mail = :mail WHERE uid = :uid',
                array(':name' => $name, ':mail' => $mail, ':uid' => $account->uid));
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Drupal 6 syntax, you need to convert it to Drupal 7 syntax:

```
db_update('users')
  ->fields(array('name' => $name, 'mail' => $mail))
  ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
  ->execute();
```

See the [Database API docs](https://drupal.org/developing/api/database) for more details.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that i have already tried like that and its not creating user account with valid names but with random names.So that only i am trying to  exactly replace the query and get exact results, which i am not getting rite now . In above function, You can able to see where it is creating user account with names and email. Where as wit this query its creating random names instead of valid names

Comment: What do you mean by 'random' exactly? Whatever you have in `$name` will be put into the database, you're totally in control of that. Drupal, nor MySQL, will not change that to 'random', it will only do what you tell it to do. You can't use `db_update()` to create a user obviously, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: This is ubercart guest checkout module and there is a bug in it. I am trying to avoid that error. The error comes when i checkout as guest account and buy the product and then submit,it will create an buyer account with given names in the ubercart form. With above function it does all,creates user account properly. only issue over here is that it says  Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be an array, string given.

Comment: You can't possibly be getting that error if you're using the Drupal 7 code that you've put in your question. If you're still getting that error, it's because you're using `db_query()` incorrectly as in your _first_ code example. You need to use the code I've provided in the answer. If that doesn't "work", then your problem is somewhere else. That query is 100% valid, I can promise you.

Comment: In order to avoid that error i am trying to change that above query db_query('UPDATE {users} SET name = "%s", mail = "%s" WHERE uid = %d', $name, $mail, $account->uid); but if change to db_update it creates user account with random names like anon-564556 etc, random mail id anon-58965655@mail.com but not with ubercart filled name and email id.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. `db_update()` **cannot create an account, it can only update an existing database record**. So I'm not really sure what you're asking

Comment: Its not my module and its a ubercart guest checkout module. why cant you see the above the function. In that it clearly states that "// For guest checkout, we replace the ubercart generated username and email
// for a new user with one that is more anonymous."  So i am guessing account is getting created here only. Hope i am not wrong ?

Comment: I'll say it one last time and then I'm out...`db_update()` cannot be used to create a new user. Never, ever. It can only ever be used to **update an existing record in the database**. You need to accept that, and continue with that knowledge in mind. If it means you have to go back and completely re-assess your understanding of that code, then that's what you'll need to do. But I'm afraid I can't tutor you through Drupal's API functions. I would recommend moving this to the module's issue queue, where you can get help from the guy who actually wrote it, and you can ask him what's going on

Comment: I can understand db_update cant create new user account. Error is coming in that line. Since above given comment "// For guest checkout, we replace the ubercart generated username and email // for a new user with one that is more anonymous." in the module, so  i thought its getting created like that. Sorry For the trouble.

Comment: @Ram No need to apologise it's no trouble, I just don't think the Q+A format here is going to allow us to give you the support it looks like you might need to fix this. The problem you're having isn't being caused by what you're describing. The code in this answer would definitely, 100% fix that error. If that then introduces _new_ problems, and then fixing that one breeds another one, and so on, this really will turn into a support forum